# SELECT * Not returning all rows, unless I ORDER BY id DESC

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

Application presented with "Sequence Contains More Than One Entity" error.  Knowing this is usually the result of a .SingleOrDefault() command in Linq, I started investigating.  I can verify that the production server has many instances of duplicate keywords, so that's where I begin.

I have the following Keyword table:

- id      INT (NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY)
- text    NVARCHAR(512)
- active  INT

active is just a way to "enable/disable" data if the need strikes me.  I'm using LINQ to SQL and have the following method implemented:

```
public Keyword GetKeyword(String keywordText)
{
    return db.Keywords.SingleOrDefault(k => (k.text.ToUpper() == keywordText.ToUpper()));
}
```

The idea is that I attach keywords through an association table so that multiple objects can reference the same keyword.  There should be no duplicate text entries within the Keyword table.  This is not enforced on the database, but rather through code.  This might not be best practice, but that is the least of my problems at the moment.  So when I create my object, I do this:

```
Keyword keyword = GetKeyword(keywordText)
if(keyword == null)
{
    keyword = new Keyword();
    keyword.text = keywordText;
    keyword.active = Globals.ACTIVE;
    db.Keywords.InsertOnSubmit(keyword);
}
KeywordReference reference = new KeywordReference();
reference.keywordId = keyword.id;
myObject.KeywordReferences.Add(reference);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

this code is actually paraphrased, I use a repository pattern, so all relevant code would be much longer.  However, I can assure you the code is working as intended, as I've extensively tested it.  The problem seems to be happening on the database level.

So I run a few tests and manual queries on my test database and find that the keyword I passed in my tests is not in the database, yet if I do a JOIN, I see that it is.  So I dig a little deeper and opt to manually scan through the whole list:

```
SELECT * FROM Keyword
```

return 737 results.  I decided I didn't want to look through them all, so I ORDER BY text and get 737 results.  I look for the word I recently added, and it does not show up in the list.

Confused, I do a lookup for all keywordIds associated with the object I recently worked on and see a few with ids over 1,000 (the id is set to autoincrement by 1).  Knowing that I never actually delete a keyword (hence the "Active" column) so all ids from 1 to at least those numbers over 1,000 should all be present, I do another query:

```
SELECT * FROM Keyword ORDER BY id
```

returns 737 results, max ID stops at 737.  So I try:

```
SELECT * FROM Keyword ORDER BY id DESC
```

returns 1308 rows

I've seen disparities like this before if there is no primary key or no unique identifier, but I have confirmed that the id column is, in fact, both.  I'm not really sure where to go from here, and I now have the additional problem of about 4,000+ keywords on production that are duplicate, and several more objects that reference different instances of each.

Comment: FWIW, this sounds a lot to me like a corrupt table or index.

Comment: Does this query return any rows: `declare @Max as Int = ( select Max( Id ) from Keyword ); with Numbers as ( select 1 as Number union all select Number + 1 from Numbers where Number < @Max ) select Number from Numbers as N left outer join Keyword as K on K.Id = N.Number where K.Id is NULL`

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error.  This is possible.  I did an INSERT into a new table using the SELECT * ORDER BY id DESC and can now query the new table as expected.

Comment: @HABO.  I get an error:
The statement terminated.  The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: Addition a maxrecursion option fixes the query: `declare @Max as Int = ( select Max( Id ) from Keyword ); with Numbers as ( select 1 as Number union all select Number + 1 from Numbers where Number < @Max ) select Number from Numbers as N left outer join Keyword as K on K.Id = N.Number where K.Id is NULL option ( maxrecursion 0 )`  Running it on the original table would display any gaps in the `Id` values.

Comment: @HABO I get 92 results:  every number from 738 to 829.  Since I have no code that actually deletes from the database, this is odd.

Comment: @AceCorban - It isn't odd if inserts failed or transactions were rolled back.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense.  So is there any explanation as to why such a thing might cause the table to think there are less rows than there are, and why an ORDER BY id DESC changes that?  As I mentioned earlier, I was able to create a new table and insert all of the rows into the new table, and I am able to query the new table just fine.

Comment: @AceCorban - Did you actually query the count, e.g. `select Count(42) from ( select top 100 percent Id from Keyword order by Id desc ) as Ace`, (or `@@ROWCOUNT` or number of rows returned) or did you just look at the largest `Id`?

Comment: By specifying án order by you may affect the index used by the SQL Engineer to 'walk down' the candidate row list. In this case the Id is the primary key column, therefore the query plan ignores the auxiliary index and goes straight to the table. What database are you using? I've seen this kind of behavior with a corrupt database in MS Access.

Comment: @HABO  that's a good point, I was verifying the MAX id by looking at the first entry when I ordered by id DESC.  The SELECT COUNT() query yields 737, actually.

Comment: @Galdur  I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'm pretty sure you and 500 are right that we are just looking at a corrupt table since I was able to create a new table using a SELECT ORDER BY id DESC from the old table and query it.  This doesn't really solve the problem on production since the damage has been done, but for the time being, I have replaced the instance of .SingleOrDefault to .FirstOrDefault to at least stop the errors.  Now I need to figure out how to change all the various references to duplicates and remove the duplicates.  And I'm probably a 6/10 in SQL talent.

Comment: Talk to your DBA and have them start running regularly scheduled corruption checks with DBCC, etc.

Comment: Start with a dbcc checkdb on the database. I think the index is corrupt but that the table is ok.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys to your table so you can identify the referencing tables and columns? You can try to get snapshots of the different selects and create an update statement for all referencing tables using those different row sets.

Comment: Another thing: It makes a difference for the repair script if the clustered index contains the big result set and the nonclustered indexes only contain subsets or vice versa.

Comment: Our biggest problem is that we have a lack of sufficient talent.  We actually have no DBA, and are limited by my ability to administrate SQL Server which, to say the least, is not my best talent and is even further complicated by the fact that I do not have direct access to the box.  Policy, however, cannot be changed because this is a government operation and I'm just a lowly contractor.  I will do some research into your suggestions and see what I can do.  In the meantime, I think you have all given me enough to think about.  

How do I mark this topic as "Resolved" or "Closed"?

Comment: @CSharper yeah, I can get a look at all the references to duplicate entries.  There is only one table that references Keyword, it is a many to many association table with a central table.  This association table has references to duplicate Keywords somewhere in the 4,000s on production, so I won't be able to do this piecemeal.  I'm assuming a loop through an UPDATE WHERE IN(SELECT) type procedure will get me most of the way there, then I could probably just remove any Keyword that has no references.  I'll see what I can come up with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you somehow can get all your data then your table is fine, but index is corrupted.

Try to rebuild index on your table:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Your.Table
REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);
```

In rare situations you can see such errors if your hard drive fails to write data due to power loss. Chkdsk should help

Comment: Thanks.  I've managed to repair the table on production from a backup, but I'll keep this query handy to try in the future.  The problem with the table now is the damage that has been done.  Duplicates were introduced when the application could not find keywords by name, even though they were there.  That now remains the problem, though not technically part of this question.